# Android display captured image from Camera in CircleImageView

Tags: java, android, image, camera, gallery

I searched in the forum for similar questions but I haven't found a correct answer for my code.
I have an activity in which user can choose (from a Dialog) if to upload a photo from gallery or to take it with camera. I'd like to show in a CircularImageView the photo chosen by the user. I was able to do it for images picked from gallery, but unfortunately it doesn't work if I take it with camera.
This is the layout code of CircularImageView:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/add_profile_photo_round"
            app:civ_border_width="0dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#000000" />
```

And this is the Java code:

```
TextView take_photo = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
...
take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhotoFromCamera();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
pick_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                        options);

                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

As I already said, it works with images from gallery but not with captured one.
Thank you for your help
P.S. sorry if my English is bad

Edit: I tried to modify the code but it still doesn't work

```
else if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "r");
                assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
                FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Second edit: I have used this code but it still doesn't work:

```
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Objects.requireNonNull(data.getData()), "r");
                assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
                FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Did you try my answer? If you did and it worked, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it doesn't work, I had edited my post to show new code I'm using, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have a look.. You should use `data.getData` instead of `fileUri`. I tested it and it's working. I edited my answer after you edited.

Comment: Yes, I had edited the post with data.getData() instead of fileUri, but it still doesn't work... You tested it and it's working...? Probably then there's another error in my code

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Now I'm not at home, but when I run it, it shows nothing when I take a picture with camera. Later I'll check if there are errors, but I think I had already checked and there weren't. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218839/discussion-between-tommaso-and-hb).

Comment: Have a look at my new edit, I think this will be your best option long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can be useful for other people, I found this code and it works:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 3):

`fileUri.getPath()` should not be used, you don't know if the `Uri` is pointing to a file. Change your bitmap to the following

```java
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r"); 
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor); 
parcelFileDescriptor.close();
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

---

Edit:

I think the best solution, long term, would be to use an image cache library. The reason is, you might run into `OutOfMemoryException`, plus it handles everything for you. I would recommend [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).

First implement it, by adding the following to your app-level `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Then change your `onActivityResult` to the following:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY || requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Picasso.get().load(data.getData()).fit().centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder) // You can add a placeholder while the image loads
            .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error) // You can add an image for when there's an error loading image from Gallery
            .into(image);
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you are using version `2.71828` it should not happen. Please try invalidate cache and restart, by going to `File`-`Invalidate Caches / Restart`. This should fix it

Comment: I tried, but if I upload image from gallery it shows R.drawable.user_placeholder_error, taking photo from camera it shows R.drawable.user_placeholder